# When building a Haskell dependency with Nix, how to avoid building executables?

Tags: haskell, nix

In my `.nix` file I have packages `foo` and `bar`, with `bar` depending on `foo`:

```
let
  haskellPackages = reflex-platform.ghcjs.override {
    overrides = self: super: {
      foo =
        pkgs.haskell.lib.dontCheck
          (pkgs.haskell.lib.dontHaddock
             (self.callCabal2nix "foo" ./foo { }));
      bar = self.callCabal2nix "bar" ./bar { };
    };
  };

in
  haskellPackages.bar
```

How can I disable building executables contained in `foo`? I only want to build the library.

I tried `overrideCabal`, but without luck. This still builds the `foo` executable:

```
let
  haskellPackages = reflex-platform.ghcjs.override {
    overrides = self: super: {
      foo =
        pkgs.haskell.lib.overrideCabal
          (pkgs.haskell.lib.dontCheck
             (pkgs.haskell.lib.dontHaddock
                (self.callCabal2nix "foo" ./foo { })));
          (drv: { isExecutable = false; });
      bar = self.callCabal2nix "bar" ./bar { };
    };
  };

in
  haskellPackages.bar
```

I can reproduce the same problem with GHC instead of GHCJS.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @semicolon It's been too long, I don't remember anymore.

Answer (score 1):

In your example you could use:

```
foo = pkgs.haskell.lib.compose.setBuildTarget "lib:foo" (...)
```

There are a handful of similar functions available:

```
pkgs.haskell.lib.compose.setBuildTargets
pkgs.haskell.lib.compose.setBuildTarget
pkgs.haskell.lib.setBuildTargets
pkgs.haskell.lib.setBuildTarget
```